# Draw UIBezierPath outside of UIView::drawRect()?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uigraphicscontext

I'm trying to draw a set of small circles around the edge of a view to mirror physical lights (pixels) I'm controlling in my app. These circles will change color frequently. So I've created a PixelSimulator object to draw each circle into a custom UIView object.

Here's the relevant code

```
class PixelSimulator {
  let size: CGSize;
  let color: UIColor;
  let pixelPath: UIBezierPath;

  init (point: CGPoint, size: CGSize, pixel: Pixel) {
    self.point = point;
    self.size = size;
    self.pixel = pixel;

    pixelRect = CGRect(origin: point, size: size);
    pixelPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: pixelRect);

    color = pixel.color;
  }

  func render () {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    color.setFill();
    pixelPath.fill();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  }
}
```

I've tried a different approach using `CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, pixelRect)` to no avail. I've also tried declaring the pixelPath inside of the `render()` method, also to no avail.

What do I need to change to get my bezierPath drawn onto the screen at any time, inside of `drawRect()` or out of it?

Comment: What is your plan with the image context? When are you calling render?

Comment: I'm calling `render()` when ever the corresponding physical light's color changes.

Comment: From where? In draw rect? Setting the view to display when they change? I wouldn't use an image context, I'd draw straight to the view or a layer.

Comment: The colors for the physical lights are changed elsewhere in the app. Effectively, when the physical light's color changes, the corresponding `PixelSimulator`'s `color` changes to match and `render()` is called. This happens outside of `drawRect()`. If I drew into a layer every time the color changes, wouldn't I end up with tons of layers? Would that be a problem? And if not, could you post an answer explaining how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the image context and just directly draw. I'd call `render` only from inside draw rect.

When the colour changes I'd update the appropriate simulators and post a notification to let the 'system' know that it happened. In this case a notification is appropriate because you don't want to know what is interested about the change event and multiple things in the system may be interested.

When the notification is received by your view controller it simply calls `setNeedsDisplay` on the view which will result in the simulators being rendered on the next draw cycle.

Comment: This approach worked and is probably much more efficient than what I had in mind. Thanks muchly.